# Make Map ref object available on first modal window render/launch

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

I have a table where when I click on a row of the table, I get the content/objects of the row which I am passing to the Dialog component that uses

react-map-gl

to display the item's location based on the xy coordinate.

When clicked it shows the map, but the issue is that the mapref returns null on the first render, when I console.log(mapref) shows null instead of the available mapref objects which I can use such as flyTo(), setCenter() etc. I know it's supposed to show null on the initial render but not when I launch the Modal.

The complete code

```
import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

import MapGl, {
  FullscreenControl,
  NavigationControl,
  Marker,
  Popup
} from "react-map-gl";

export default function MapDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    latitude: 6.4444,
    longitude: 7.4909,
    zoom: 10,
    
  });

  const mapRef = useRef(null);

  //makeshift data
  const rowData = {
    laty: 5.4959,
    longx: 7.0807
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(mapRef.current); // does not render the map methods on first modal render
    if (mapRef.current) {
    mapRef.current?.setCenter({
      lat: rowData?.laty,
      lng: rowData?.longx
    });
   }
  }, [rowData]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClickOpen}> open map </button>
      <Dialog
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"
        open={open}
        PaperProps={{
          sx: {
            minWidth: 500,
            minHeight: 400
          }
        }}
      >
        <DialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title" onClose={handleClose}>
          Map
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent dividers>
          <MapGl
            ref={mapRef}
            initialViewState={viewport}
            mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"
            style={{
              height: "calc(100vh - 64px)",
              width: "100%"
            }}
            onViewStateChange={(viewState) => setViewport(viewState)}
            mapboxAccessToken="pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4M29iazA2Z2gycXA4N2pmbDZmangifQ.-g_vE53SD2WrJ6tFX7QHmA"
            attributionControl={true}
            interactive={true}
            showCompass={true}
          >
            <NavigationControl />
            <Marker
              className="marker"
              key={rowData?.laty}
              longitude={rowData?.longx}
              latitude={rowData?.laty}
              offsetTop={(-viewport.zoom * 5) / 2}
              anchor="bottom"
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
            >
              <svg data-name="marker" width="20" height="48">
                <ellipse
                  cx="10"
                  cy="27"
                  rx="9"
                  ry="5"
                  fill="#c4c4c4"
                  opacity=".3"
                />
                <path
                  data-name="shadow"
                  fill="#bfbfbf"
                  d="M10 32c5 0 9-2.2 9-5s-4-5-9-5-9 2.2-9 5 4 5 9 5Z"
                  fillRule="evenodd"
                  opacity=".3"
                />
                <path
                  fill="#4264fb"
                  stroke="#314ccd"
                  strokeWidth=".5"
                  d="M19.25 10.4a13.066 13.066 0 0 1-1.46 5.223 41.528 41.528 0 0 1-3.247 5.549 71.377 71.377 0 0 1-4.542 5.945l-.217-.258a73.206 73.206 0 0 1-4.327-5.725 42.268 42.268 0 0 1-3.246-5.553A12.978 12.978 0 0 1 .75 10.4 9.466 9.466 0 0 1 10 .75a9.466 9.466 0 0 1 9.25 9.65Z"
                />
                <path
                  fill="#fff"
                  stroke="#314ccd"
                  strokeWidth=".5"
                  d="M13.55 10A3.55 3.55 0 1 1 10 6.45 3.548 3.548 0 0 1 13.55 10Z"
                />
                <path fill="none" d="M0 0h20v48H0z" />
              </svg>
            </Marker>
          </MapGl>
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    </>
  );
}
```

how can I solve this?

Please see sandbox for better context

https://xbzi8r.csb.app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed from useRef() to useState and it worked, useState triggers re-render which worked perfectly.

```
const [mapRef, setMapRef] = useState(null)

 useEffect(() => {
    if (mapRef) {
    mapRef?.setCenter({
      lat: rowData?.laty,
      lng: rowData?.longx
    });
   }
  }, [rowData,mapRef]);

<Map  ref={(ref) => setMapRef(ref)}/>
```